# How to color cells based on value

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I'm trying to use pyplot to illustrate a layout in a robotic path planning RL concept.

I've created the layout as below, but I cannot get the cells to color based on the value of the cell. I've used an np.array to generate the image and pyplot, but matlib colors it based on a std heatmap.

I have tried the following just to color all cells as a start:

```
ax.set_facecolor('red')
```

But it seem to color the plot behind the ax.imshow, rendering it hidden on the illustration.

The entire .py:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

layout = np.array([
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
im = ax.imshow(layout)


ax.set_xticks(np.arange(len(layout[1])))
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(len(layout)))

# Rotate the tick labels and set their alignment.
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45, ha="right",
         rotation_mode="anchor")

# Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
for i in range(len(layout)):
    for j in range(len(layout[1])):
        text = ax.text(j, i, layout[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="w")
        ax.set_facecolor('red')

ax.set_title("Showroom layout")
fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

I know the set_facecolor right now will color the entire plot red, but im still debugging. In the future it will color cells with value "1" gray and "0" white. Or alike.

I appreciate your help and input! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the way the `imshow` works. By default, it uses a range of colors called `viridis` but you can use others. For instance, `gray` will give you a scale between white for 0 and black for 1. But if you want gray for 1, you need to create your own cmap. See below. It just creates a variation of color that is white for the min value (here 0) and gray for the max value (here 1).

```py
from matplotlib.colors import Colormap, ListedColormap
cmap = ListedColormap(["white", "gray"])
im = ax.imshow(layout, cmap=cmap)
```

if you want to still see the numbers, you may want to chose the color of the text based on the value:

```py
# Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
for i in range(len(layout)):
    for j in range(len(layout[1])):
        text = ax.text(j, i, layout[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color='gray' if layout[i, j] == 0 else 'white')
```

**Output**:
[image: output grid]

**EDIT**: If you need more than 2 colors and don't wan't a gradient but rather specific colors you can use the below. It will use each color to match its index (you can use RGB format too (255,0,0) for less common colors)

```py
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap
cmap=ListedColormap(["red", "blue", "green", "black"])
plt.imshow(a, cmap=cmap)
# Loop over data dimensions and create text annotations.
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(len(a[1])):
        text = plt.text(j, i, a[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color='white')
```

[image: with several colors]

**Note:**: if the numbers in your plot exceed the length of the color list, it will try to spread it and you will lose a bit the control. You could also use the `N` parameter of the `ListedColormap` that allows you to repeat the color order until `N`, in my example, with `N=6`, the colormap would be `["red", "blue", "green", "black", "red", "blue"]`

Comment: Hmm, I'll take it!
- Does not quite solve the issue, as I cant specifically bind a value to a certain color. But using the "accent" color scheme, did allow me to get distinct colorschemes for all values.

I ended up just using the following line instead: im = ax.imshow(layout, cmap=plt.get_cmap("Accent"))

But since you lead me to the cmap parameter, I will accept your answer and open a new question, if I need specific colors :) - Thx

Comment: Didn't realise you had more colors than 0 or 1. There is actually a quick upgrad of the answer that will suit you. See my edit :)